# When value of $this->session->userdata('username') is compared in an if statement, the if else statement always go to the else part

Tags: codeigniter

We have been developing a system and we just spotted this kind of error and we have tried conditions that we think is logically correct but we always directed to the else part. In our system, we have assigned every value of the users email logging in the system to the `this->session->userdata('username')`. When a certain user logged in using his own email account,automatically the value of the `$this->session->userdata('username')` is the email of that user who logged in.However, if I change my email in the url part using other user email, I am directed to that account so what we did we have made condition in the if statement part. Here is the code:

```
public function get_course()
{

   if($this->session->userdata['username']==$this->uri->segment(3)) {

      $data=$this->data;

      $tennant_url_id=$this->uri->segment(3);

      if(!empty($tennant_url_id)) {
         $tennant_code=$tennant_url_id;
      } else {
         $tennant_code=$this->session->userdata('username');
      }

      $num_row=$this->session->userdata('total_row');
      $total_row=$this->course_booking_model->check_tennant($tennant_code);
      $data['tennant_id'] = $tennant_code;
      $data['total_row']=$total_row;
      $data['data']=$this->course_booking_model->get_all_courses($tennant_code);
      $this->load->view('view_course_admin',$data);

   } else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('Sess_expire', 'Your session has expired! Please Login again.');

      redirect("/admin/logout");
   }
}
```

It works fine when I change the email in the url then I am logged out. But if I click in any of the link of my page or refresh the page without even changing the email in the url, the else part is always executed and directed to the log out page. Can anybody figure out what is the problem here? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your best bet is to echo out the value of both variables before you do any logic. That way you can see whats happening depending on your url, etc. `echo 'user: '.$this->session->userdata['username'].' | uri: '. $this->uri->segment(3);die();`

Comment: Yeah,I already do that. They have the same value.

Comment: Im having a lot of experiment just to reveal what is the real error here. When I remove the content in the if part but the same if parameter condition and just echoed a word and then refresh it, it works fine, I am no longer redirected to the else part. The code seems running right.However, if I get my original if content back, I  do get the same error back again even just by refreshing the page. I do not know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing,

```
if($this->session->userdata['username'] == $this->uri->segment(3))
```

should be:

```
//not square brackets but regular brackets
if($this->session->userdata('username') == $this->uri->segment(3))
```

Comment: yes..I tried it already but still the same result. $this->session->userdata['username'] and $this->session->userdata('username') have the same value as I echoed both of them. Thank you for helping Mudshark.

Comment: Im having a lot of experiment just to reveal what is the real error here. When I remove the content in the if part but the same if parameter condition and just echoed a word and then refresh it, it works fine, I am no longer redirected to the else part. The code seems running right.However, if I get my original if content back, I  do get the same error back again even just by refreshing the page. I do not know what's wrong here.

Comment: The whole secundary if/else block in your initial if is redundant, because you have already checked for the session username to equal the uri segment 3. What happens if you simply replace all that with `$tennant_code = $this->uri->segment(3);`?